# Recyclerview holder mixes on scroll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When scroll recyclerview some items mixes. After I add ads after every 15 items, holder get wrong data. Some items are vip items. I will change background color of these items. But when I scroll it dublicates mixes. How can I solve?

This is my adapter

```
private Context mCtx;
private List<Car> carList;
private RecyclerViewAnimator mAnimator;
private int AD_TYPE=1;
private int CONTENT_TYPE=2;
private int LIST_AD_DELTA=15;

public ProductAllCarAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView,Context mCtx, List<Car> carList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.carList = carList;
    mAnimator = new RecyclerViewAnimator(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType == AD_TYPE){
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_add_item, null);
        ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder vh = new ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder(itemView);
        mAnimator.onCreateViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    } else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_car_item, null);
        ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder vh = new ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder(itemView);
        mAnimator.onCreateViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position>0 && position % LIST_AD_DELTA == 0)
        return AD_TYPE;
    return CONTENT_TYPE;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductAllCarAdapter.ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE) {
        final Car car = carList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        GlideApp.with(mCtx).load(car.getImg()).into(holder.imageView);

        if (car.getVip() == 1) {
            holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mCtx, R.color.colorVip));
            holder.imageViewVIP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        final String carid = String.valueOf(car.getCarid());
        mAnimator.onBindViewHolder(holder.itemView, position);

    } else {
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context mcontext = view.getContext();
                Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(mcontext, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, AdsItem.class);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent, bundle);
            }
        });

        mAnimator.onBindViewHolder(holder.itemView, position);
    }
}

private int getRealPosition(int position) {
    if (LIST_AD_DELTA == 0) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return position - position / LIST_AD_DELTA;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {   return position;   }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int additionalContent = 0;
    if (carList.size() > 0 && carList.size() > LIST_AD_DELTA) {
        additionalContent = ( carList.size() / LIST_AD_DELTA);
    }
    return carList.size() + additionalContent;
}

public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View mView;
    ImageView imageView, imageViewVIP;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageViewVIP = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVIP);
        relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutpc);

    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        mView.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

I think problem `onBindViewHolder` function use wrong holder. `ArrayList` also return true value but on scroll it mixes.

Comment: I think it should be `additionalContent = (carList.size()  /LIST_AD_DELTA);` in `getItemCount()`.

Comment: yes I try this, but nothing changes

Comment: I tried but nothing

Comment: I add item view type for Ads. After this it mixes. Maybe getItemCount or wrong holder position

Comment: in `onBindViewHolder`, try by changing
`if (getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE) {`

to

`if (getItemViewType(holder.getAdapterPosition()) == CONTENT_TYPE) {`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the corresponding `else` of the following `if` statement block.

```
if (car.getVip() == 1) {
   holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mCtx, R.color.colorVip));
   holder.imageViewVIP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mCtx, R.color.colorNormal));
    holder.imageViewVIP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This is inside your `onBindViewHolder` function where the view type is `CONTENT_TYPE`.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Great to know that. Please consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it is correct. Thanks.